# Какую схему лучше выбрать для хранения комментариев к статье?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Исходя из опыта поделитесь аргументами и опытом как лучше организовать схему хранения комментариев к статье, комментарий могут быть вложенными (дерево).

Как я понял, лучший вариант это одна колеекция объектов статей, с полем массивом comments в котором все комментарии к статье. Для комментариев на комментарии (ответ не к статье а на уже имеющийся комментарий), аналогично в объекте комментария добавить массив comments. 
Так вроде бы все отлично, но теперь не пойму как быстро найти нужный комментарий по его ID одним запросом, понятно что можно перебирать все вложенные и искать, но это будет не рационально.

Comment: *комментарий могут быть вложенными* То есть дерево. Значит, для хранения нужно использовать структуру, предназначенную именно для хранения и обработки деревьев.

Comment: Я тоже пришёл к этому решению на момент проектирования. Но теперь тестируя выборки столкнулся со сложностью поиска нужного комментария в дереве, возможно я не знаю нужную команду в mongo?

Comment: *столкнулся со сложностью поиска нужного комментария в дереве* А по какому признаку ищется комментарий - пользователю, дате, подстроке, нескольким критериям? И что именно по этому признаку ищется - только комментарий или вся ветка вплоть до статьи?

Comment: нужна выборка комментария с вложенными коментариями по идентификатору (id) комментария

Comment: Иными словами - ветка от заданного по ID узла до листьев. Это легко делается в любой tree-ориентированной системе хранения.

Comment: понятно, это можно сделать и в скрипте mongo shell рекурсивной функцией javascript, но вопрос как найти в дереве элемент по ID средствами команд mongo